# How can I subclass UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ReplyContent: UIView {
    var body: String?
    var image: UIImage?

    convenience init(body: String?, image: UIImage?){
        self.body = body
        self.image = image
        self.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The error states: "Cannot invoke ReplyContent.init with no arguments.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `super.init()` instead of `self.init()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just do `UIView.init()` with no arguments. You need `UIView.init(frame:)` or `UIView.init(coder:)`.